# Setup a virtual environment for pip work and conda work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda, virtual-environment

OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I want to setup my machine so I have two virtual environments

1. For pip
2. For conda

I want to do this so in one virtual environment I can have all libraries that are installed using pip and in the other I can have all my anaconda work/libraries

For pip and conda both I want to a have Python3.6 as default

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [install Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html).  You can then create an environment where you (try to) only use `conda`

```
> conda create -n conda_only python=3.6
> conda install -n conda_only numpy ...
```

And you can also make your 'pip' environment as a conda env, but then only use `pip` to install packages.  For example,

```
> conda create -n pip_only python=3.6 pip
> source activate pip_only
> pip install numpy ...
```

I don't know your motivation (benchmarking installation times perhaps?), but it should be noted that in practice it's common to mix `conda` and `pip` simply because some packages are only on PyPI.  Plus, conda recognizes packages installed by pip.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. If I use both pip and conda in the same environment then conda wouldn't pickup libraries installed via pip and vice versa right ?

Comment: @TanmayBhatnagar, no that is not correct. Conda will recognize pip-installed packages, and pip will recognize conda-installed *python* packages (those that install to `.../site-packages`). They work well together. My typical workflow is to use conda for everything, and I resort to pip only when a package isn't available through conda.  Also, conda envs are cheap, so just make some and play around.

Comment: so do u use the preinstalled pip or did you install pip using conda as well

Comment: @TanmayBhatnagar You need a pip installation for each virtual environment, so you install pip via conda for each environment.  pip is only a package manager, but conda is both a virtual environment manager and a package manager.

Comment: the problem i encountered was after activating the conda env i did not install pip using conda and just installed libraries using pip so conda did not pickup the libraries

Comment: Also, I installed opencv using this script https://github.com/tanmay-bhatnagar/HandwrittenDigitRecognition/blob/master/install-opencv.sh inside an environment and conda didn't pick it up